# Resource not found in Android Firemonkey app

Tags: android, c++, delphi, cross-platform, firemonkey

I added resource file in Project -> Resources and images.

When I run app on Windows, resource is found, but not found when i run on Android device.

```
TResourceStream * rs = new TResourceStream(HInstance, "String_ressource", RT_RCDATA);
```

Why that ?

Comment: Because this way of adding resources to an executable only works on Windows.

Comment: Cross-platform did they say ? Thanks for answer btw

Comment: If this is the case, then it's a limitation of the Android executable, not a fault of Embarc.

Comment: nolaspeaker  This is incorrect. It should work on all platforms. I used resources (png images) in Android and iOS in my components in the same way and I checked it on Android, iOS and Windows.